# Punctuation fix needed in close dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, typographical-error

In the close dialog, this reason

> Questions on professional server, networking, or related
>   infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>   they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be
>   able to get help on Server Fault.

has a [serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). However, this reason

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

does not. Please add a comma after "library". It will save the world... or something.

Comment: Or, please remove the comma after `networking`.

Comment: Serial commas are the new pluralization bug(s?) of the re-born Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Sam Using the serial comma would be consistent with other messages. e.g., the opinion-based reason. (`based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`)

Comment: @user3477950 Ah, pluralisation. Wouldn't it be easier if it were as simple as "Guys, see this spoon? From now on, let's call it... a spoon." "But what if there's more than one?" "Then just put an S on the end! Spoons!"

Comment: -1 -- *removing* those useless commas would save one byte per message, which seems a much better result. Also, they really *look strange* or even *incorrect* to any non-British English speaker (e.g. in Italian you *never* put commas like that).

Comment: @Bakuriu American English often uses serial commas. Personally, I never omit them. Regardless, its use should be consistent amongst the close reasons.

Comment: @Bakuriu: "would save one byte per message, which seems a much better result" Yes, throw out every iota of any grammatical reason in favor of micro-optimization. [But I don't want your drama if you really wanna leave out that Oxford comma...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc#t=1m45s)

Comment: @Bakuriu, the *missing* serial comma is, to the best of my knowledge, a relatively new phenomenon introduced by American newpapers. The comma obviously belongs there to reflect speech patterns.

Comment: @BoltClock while we're at it we should probably use the old-school neolithic approach of omitting all punctuation using mixed case also hinders compression a bit so we should skip that infactidontthinkwereallyneedspaceswecanjustputonewordafteranother

Comment: @dfeuer and we cld do like evry1 does 2day & omit all caps & sum ltrs 2! bc we rly dont need them rite?

Comment: I was taught to **not** use a comma before the "or" that introduces the last term

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant "Dear Next Person Who Opens a Serial Comma 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant `,`" I'm waiting for that tweet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration]

There. Fixed. That sentence was awkward anyway, and the serial comma certainly didn't help it .

The recommendation message is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Questions on professional server or network-related..."? The hyphen after _professional server_ looks incorrect.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: It's correct - it means "professional server-related or network-related". The hyphen you see is called a suspended hyphen, and it joins "professional server" to "related" in the next hyphenated adjective so that "related" doesn't have to be repeated each time.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock. I was unaware of suspended hyphens. It looks perfect now.